# How to get the HTML table from website on Android

Tags: android, html, android-asynctask, jsoup

I am new to Android Development and on my Android app, I want to retrieve HTML table values from website. I will use the values (in the background) which I'll get from the HTML table.

I want to get (td) values.

HTML table is like this.

```
<table width="482" height="187" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="1">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center;>
         <strong>"UKOME&nbsp;KARARI</strong>
       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>Elektronik Bilet</td>

         .....

</table>
```

Can I use the Jsoup? How?

Comment: You should open that website in `webView` and then use some `JS` to catch each line of your HTML page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jsoup library inside your android application to achieve HTML table from web site.

Using this libray you can parse html page in Android.

Download jsoup library" from http://jsoup.org/download link.

Happy Coding...

Comment: Thanks. How can I add .jar file on Android Studio ?